# Sessions lost during Server.Transfer in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

Sessions lost during `Server.Transfer(..., true)` or `Server.Transefer(..)`. Any help greatly appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: Certainly there may be code in requested page that clears/removes/abandon the session object.

Comment: @Royi Namir. Thanks. No. Page transfer is on same domain. Thanks!

Comment: @AVD. I think, we are clearingout session object during page transfer. Thanks.

Comment: not related. Session should be kept. are you moving to another page in another domain . you must be doing this manually or something

Answer (score 1):

In the web.config, try adding the following:

```
<pages enableSessionState="true" ...>
```

Comment: This solves it for me.  @James, can you go into any detail why you suggested this? In my case, I see that there is a Server.Transfer to a page without any page directives at all, which could be a reason why things didnt work for me..

Comment: @KevinDeus: I don't recall offhand, but I'll respond back with a more detailed explanation when I get a chance.